# optimal strategies for 2-player zero-sum games of perfect information

Tags: game-theory

I asked essentially this on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111779/57159) slightly more than

3 days ago, and it hasn't received any answer there.

> Do finite-state 2-player zero-sum games of perfect information with only win-draw-loss outcomes always have deterministic-and-memoryless optimal strategies for both players?

In other words, consider 2-player games of the following form:

There is a non-empty finite set of states such that neither -1 nor +1 is a state.

One of the states is designated the initial state, and each state has [a label that's either P1 or P2]

and [a finite list of probability distributions on the union of {-1,+1} with the set of states].

Starting with the initial state, the indicated player (P1 or P2) chooses one of the probability distributions,

an element is sampled from that distribution, if the element is -1 then the game

ends with the indicated player scoring -1 and the other player scoring +1, if the element is +1 then

the game ends with the indicated player scoring +1 and the other player scoring -1, and if the

element is a state then reveal that state to that player and repeat this process from that state.

If the game continues forever then both players score 0.

Is it always the case that both players have optimal strategies

that are deterministic and only depend on the current state?

Comment: Note that "always make a move that maximizes your expected score, with ties broken arbitrarily" does not work. $\:$ One could have the deterministic game with states A,B,C,D all labeled P1, A as the initial state and going to C as the only move from there, B and D as the moves from B, C as the only move from D, and P1 winning as the only move from B. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but isn't the notion of "optimal" fuzzy here? Perhaps it would help to define this. The most natural would be subgame perfect equilibrium, I think. But there you probably need to argue that it exists...

Comment: Are you asking for something other than Zermelo's theorem?

Comment: @DouglasZare : $\:$ Yes, since chance can "affect the decision making process". $\hspace{1.71 in}$

Comment: I think that the only obstruction to otherwise maximizing strategy is the wrong choice of ties which may cause the game to repeat indefinitely. The right notion here for "optimal strategy" seems to me to be an ordinary Nash equilibrium and I believe it does exist when the strategy is defined in the right way. Can you come up with an example similar to your {A,B,C,D} game where NE does not exist when ties are well resolved?

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ ​ ​ "Nash equilibrium" ​ from among strategies for the extensive-form (and thus infinite) game, or just among the memoryless strategies? ​ If the latter, then no, since there are only finitely-many such strategies. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Sorry, what precisely do you mean by ",then no..." ?

Comment: @user2925716 ​ "then the answer to your 21-hour-ago comment's question is no" $\hspace{1.56 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer But you don't seem that this answers your question given in the last two lines of your original question, why?

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ That's because there might be better strategies which [are not deterministic] $\hspace{.77 in}$ or [depend on more than just the current state] or both. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: But you asked exactly this: "Is it always the case that both players have optimal strategies
that are deterministic and only depend on the current state?" So you meant not this,but something more general after all? Also it is unnatural to require a "better strategy" while we are not sure about Nash equilibria first.

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ ​ ​ No, I meant what I asked. ​ There could easily be some theorem that guarantees the existence of optimal strategies for my case (even though in particular the expected-payoff function is not continuous), but I'm certainly not aware of any theorem which guarantees that at least one such strategy is deterministic and only depend on the current state. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: But these are your own words: There is always Nash Equilibrium for this case:  "then the answer to your 21-hour-ago comment's question is no"

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ Does ​ "There is always Nash Equilibrium for this case:" ​ have anything to do with the rest of your most recent comment? ​ ​ ​ I also don't see the relevance of your quote from me. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: My 21-hour-ago comment's question was if you can come up with a game without NE, and you claimed that the answer is "no". So there is always a deterministic and memoryless solution.

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ I only claimed that the answer is "no" if the concept is restricted to memoryless strategies. ​ ​ ​ My question does not _restrict_ to such strategies: ​ It asks a little-bit more than whether the set of optimal strategies always _includes_ such a strategy. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Your question was about *memoryless* strategies,see here: "...always have deterministic-and-memoryless optimal strategies for both players" and also the 2 last lines of you OQ: "Is it always the case that both players have optimal strategies
that are deterministic and only depend on the current state"

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ Indeed. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ Ignoring the determinism part for now, my question can be roughly-summarized as: ​ ​ ​ Consider the optimal strategies for a given player. ​ Is it necessarily the case that at least one of them is memoryless? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: It is somehow interesting for me, since I do not see the difference between "It asks a little-bit more than whether the set of optimal strategies always includes such a (meaning memoryless) strategy" and " Is it necessarily the case that at least one of them is memoryless".

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ Good. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Please, try to explain to me if I state it right, but understand it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ I believe it comes down to how you answer the question ​ "Is there a maximum element of {1,3,4} that is odd?" . ​ ​ ​ I further believe that your answer to that question is yes, and that you'd say 3 is such an element. ​ ​ ​ However, interpreted in the same manner as my OP is asking questions, the answer would be no, since [1 is not a maximum element of {1,3,4}] and [3 is not a maximum element of {1,3,4}] and [4 is not odd], so {1,3,4} does not have a maximum element that is odd. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Here you have combined *two* properties, being odd and being maximum. What is the other property for being memoryless?Is it being deterministic? If this is the case, I finally admit that I understand.Sorry for being so slow. So being a Nash equlibrium does not help since it may not be deterministic, right?

Comment: @user2925716 : ​ The other property is being an optimal strategy. ​ ​ ​ ​